# Format a mathematical exp in the browser

Tags: javascript, python

I have this mathematical expression received from the backend. How do I format?prettify this in the browser [image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! 1) why is python tagged? And 2) please visit [How to ask](https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). SO is best when you have a specific code problem to solve.

Comment: ... use MathJax?

Comment: regarding the question, (1) if you had done some research first ([search for "display math formula in browser" on DuckDuckGo](https://html.duckduckgo.com/html?q=display%20math%20formula%20in%20browser) for example) you'd have figured out the answer instantly. (2) Don't post the data as an image. (3) Specify what you're using for the backend (Python -> Which library/version? Node.js?)

Comment: Besides -- it's not clear what exactly is the representation of your formula (valid Python expression? Then use `ast` or something to parse it)

Answer (score -1):

You can either look for a third party library or just create a parser yourself.
Here's some **pseudocode**:

```
// res is received from backend
all_instances = res
list = res.split(/**| /)

htmlstring = '';
for elem in list[1:]:
  htmlstring += `<super>${elem}</super>`

document.query().innerHTML = htmlstring
```

If you want actual code, here you go

```js
// res is received from backend
let all_instances = res.split(/\*\*| /);
let htmlstring = '';

for (const elem of all_instances.slice(1)){
  htmlstring += `<super>${elem}</super>`;
}

// now you can just use document.write or something
```

Comment: But this is not Javascript, is it?

Comment: Most of my pseudocode is basically just python because it still gets the point across. You can easily translate this pseudocode into real javascript

Comment: So this is a hint, or an indication, not an answer

Comment: I guess so. The main point is to get the algorithm across

Comment: @JeremyThille Well, the code isn't necessarily the best way to explain an algorithm. [Does an answer need to have code to be considered complete? - Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267256/does-an-answer-need-to-have-code-to-be-considered-complete)

Comment: I dunno, I think the psuedocode has some problems with it too. E.g. `*` always means the Kleene star in a regexp, so it really does need to be escaped somehow. Besides, it doesn't work if last term also has an exponent: [Test case](https://tio.run/##VY1BTsMwEEX3c4pZIMU2Skwq2k1aTlKJGmdSDBM7sk2FVHr2EIcFsJr/pf/evJmLSTa6Kdc@9DTPTBkjJTxgVYt286g@ldpije12V@JO6nbzUAFovc5cWo4ld6EehxhGfDH2nXwPxWOYn51P2Xi7GhegSRO7LPRRHdUXatmtw9c8csrR@XP5W3UAQ4gobFhgJKYRw/Df1iR2lkQr5RXwL39/wNM@fUwUn@6uBb3t9U89dXADKM7A1HA4i19MdvP8DQ "JavaScript (Node.js) – Try It Online")